# Replacing a dot with empty string via gnu make on Windows

Tags: windows, makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to convert a string value `foo.bar` to `foobar` and have been unable to achieve this via `subst`

```
dot :=.                                                              
empty:=                                                              
stuff:                                                               
    @echo $(subst $(dot), $(empty), $(APP))
    @echo $(dot)$(empty)$(dot)
```

The output I receive after running `make stuff APP=foo.bar` is:

```
foo bar
..
```

Any ideas why the output still contains a space?

Comment: Try: @echo `$(subst $(dot),$(empty), $(APP))` # No space within the call to subst

Comment: Ah! thanks a ton @GezaLore, I have spent a lot more time on this than I really shd have.

Comment: Or, even simpler: `@echo $(subst .,,$(APP))`